# How to get if multiples part of strings are in a single row

Tags: jquery, sql, select

first of all I'm using MySql.

I have to create a advance search field for a website and i need to `select` if a column contains two strings.

For example, I have this row under *Activities* column.

`{"Les Mills":1,"B.PUMP":1,"B.COMBAT":0,"B.BALANCE":0,"PILATES":1,"YOGA":0,"TOTAL TRAINING":0,"CIRCUIT FIT":1,"AERODANCE":1,"B.DE SALON":1,"DANZA DEL VIENTRE":1,"BOXEO":0," BAILES LATINOS":1,"GAP":1,"ABDOMEN":0,"CICLO INDOOR":1,"STEP":1,"NATACION DE ADULTOS":1,"ESCUELA DE NATACION":1,"AQUAGYM":1,"AQUASALUD":1}`

I need to know using multiples checkboxes if the selected checkboxes is in this row.

`... WHERE Activities="%Les Mills%" AND Activities="%Aerodance%"...`

This is the jQuery I use to post the selected values into the api:

```
function advanceSearch(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var params = "&where=";
    $(".advance-search input").each(function(index){
        if ($(this).is(":CHECKED")){
            if ($(this).parent().is("#advance-horarios")){
                var name = $(this).attr("name");
                if ($(this).attr("name") === "Domingo")
                    var value = "=1";
                else
                    var value = "<>0";
                var toPost = name + value;
            }else{
                var value = " LIKE '%"+$(this).attr("name")+"%'";
                var toPost = $(this).parent().attr("title") + value;
            }
            if (params === "&where=")
                params = params + toPost;   
            else
                params = params + " AND " + toPost;
        }
    });
    $.post("API_URL", params, function(res){
        alert(res);
    });
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now. The problem was on the ***"*** *...* **"**

The solution is to use something like "**_**" in the post parameter and replace in the PHP with str_replace() function.

Answer (score 0):

you should use like keyword while checking --

`... WHERE Activities like "%Les Mills%" AND Activities like "%Aerodance%"...`

Comment: I have this: `var value = " LIKE '%"+$(this).attr("name")+"%'";`

Comment: That converts into something like this: `WHERE Activities LIKE '%asd%' AND Activities LIKE '%dsa%' ORDER BY...`